# Limit annotations to non-final fields

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, field, final

I'm working with custom annotations in Java. Is there any way to throw an error at compile time if someone tries to use the annotation on a final field?

This is my current annotation:

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Property {
    public String value();
}
```

For example, this is perfectly legal: `@Property("test") public String str;`

This, however, is not: `@Property("test2") public final String str2;`

Answer (score 1):

Use the Checker Framework to check when compiling, if the field has the modifier `final`.

https://checkerframework.org/

Comment: @mernst thank you for updating my answer and the awesome tool!